# Psake Include method not working

Tags: powershell, psake

I am writing a simple PS script with Psake and I have a problem when I try to include another ps1 file.

```
    PS C:\CI> Include .\EnvSettings.ps1
```

I have this exception

```
Exception calling "Peek" with "0" argument(s): "Stack empty."
At C:\Users\Julien\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\psake\psake.psm1:227 char:2
+     $psake.context.Peek().includes.Enqueue(($pa));
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

I had a look at psake.psm1 line 227 to see what's going on around

```
# .ExternalHelp  psake.psm1-help.xml
function Include {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=1)][string]$fileNamePathToInclude
    )
    Assert (test-path $fileNamePathToInclude -pathType Leaf) ($msgs.error_invalid_include_path -f $fileNamePathToInclude)
    $psake.context.Peek().includes.Enqueue((Resolve-Path $fileNamePathToInclude));
}
```

The code succesfully pass the Assert line.

The problem comes from the Resolve-Path $fileNamePathToInclude, it returns nothing...
If I try it from the command line it works fine.

Anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to include a file is not `Include .\EnvSettings.ps1` , but just *"dot source"* the file :

```
. .\EnvSettings.ps1
```